# Route parameters not getting preserved [Mvc SiteMap Provider]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a `Team` table, and a `Player` table, with `TeamId` as the foreign key.

I need to do CRUD operations on players, for which I have a `PlayerController`. The `Index` methods takes `teamId` as parameter, and shows all players in that team. The `Add` method also takes `teamId` as parameter, and adds a player to that team. The `Edit` method takes `playerId` as parameter, and edits the corresponding player.

Now, I am using [Mvc SiteMap Provider](http://maartenba.github.io/MvcSiteMapProvider/getting-started.html) to create menus and breadcrumbs in my project. Showing only the relevant attributes, a part of my sitemap looks as follows:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Player List" preservedRouteParameters="teamId">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Add Player" preservedRouteParameters="teamId"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit Player" preservedRouteParameters="playerId"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

The problem is that when I navigate to `Add Player` from `Player List`, I can get back to `Player List` page by clicking on the link in the breadcrumb. But when I try going back to the `Player List` page from the `Edit Player` page, there is an error, because the URL created by the breadcrumb does not include the `teamId` parameter.

So basically the `teamId` parameter for `Player List` is preserved when I go to `Add Player`, but not when I go to `Edit Player`.

Why is it so? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because `preservedRouteParameters` only knows about the values in the current request. When navigating to the `Edit Player` link, there is no `teamId` in the request so the `Player List` link won't have a value for `teamId` to make a copy of.

You can fix this by adding the `teamId` to the `Edit Player` node.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Player List" preservedRouteParameters="teamId">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Add Player" preservedRouteParameters="teamId"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit Player" preservedRouteParameters="playerId,teamId"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

And to add the `teamId` to the associated route, ActionLinks, RouteLinks, etc. so it will be included in the request every time `Edit Player` is navigated to.

Note that it is important to make the `teamId` reference the same entity in each node with the same common ancestry.

Comment: So if I want to navigate further down the hierarchy (child tables of `Player`, say `Role`), I'd have to pass the `teamId` and the `playerId` and all other Ids corresponding to each level in the hierarchy, down to the bottommost level. My route should look like `Team/3/Player/27/Role/73/Edit` instead of `Team/Player/EditRole/73`. Is that right?

Comment: If using `preservedRouteParameters`, yes. Or you could combine segment with value like `/Team-3/Player-27/Role-73/Edit` to make it more readable. Alternatively, you could use a dynamic node provider with the shorter URLs, but that would mean loading the entire table as nodes. But `preservedRouteParameters` is cleaner for CRUD operations. See this article for demos of each approach: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position